# async IFileProvider (Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Suppose I have a component with `async Task<byte[]> GetContent(string)` method.
Should I implement the `IFileProvider` interface with blocking (like 'Wait', or 'Result')?

```
    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath)
    {
        Task<byte[]> bufferLoadTask = m_MyComponent.GetContent(subpath);
        var buffer = bufferLoadTask.Result;
        return new QuestionFileInfo(buffer);
    }
    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath){throw new NotSupportedException("not relevant");}
    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter){throw new NotSupportedException("not relevant");}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Provide more context as to what you are trying to achieve and why.

Comment: *In general*, if you're writing a library (is that your context here?) you should only offer async and sync variants if you have genuinely async and sync variants. Otherwise, only offer the actual variants you have and leave it to the *consumer* to decide whether to wrap one as the other.

Comment: An implementation of the IFileProvider interface is intended to serve razor views from a database. There is a caching database access component providing async’d methods I’d like to reuse. The initial attempt was to DI this existing DAC into my implementation and based on database search either to return bytes or to return null to continue with other providers.
Currently I decided to share specific state between some custom middleware and the IFileProvider implementation and do the async loading at first request made to the application.
Therefore, the question has lost its urgency.
thanks